# Why are there 2 transformation orientations in the viewport header?

Tags: 3d-view

I've just started using Blender 2.91 and noticed there are now two transformation orientations in the 3D viewport. The left one affects the gizmo and does what I expect it to but the right one has no effect but is where I can add a custom orientation.

The annoying thing is the (,) shortcut selects the right one which is not what I want.

Is there a way to set up a short cut to select the left orientation?

[image: Viewport header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left one is for the transform orientation of the 'Move' tool in the tool panel.

[image]

When you use other tools, the left one will be changed.

The right one is for operators. When you press shortcut g/r/s, it will use the transform orientation on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting it seems that the left orientation is an override for the right one. If it's set to default then the right orientation works as expected. This was very confusing as the tooltip show the same for both. Maybe there is a scenario for the override but personally I can't see one.

That said Blender still rocks!